Pyomo did not find license for solvers
I worked with pyomo to solve MINLP.
After i updated pyomo to the latest version pyomo-6.7.3, i get the error:
ValueError: gams is not licensed.
I checked, if gams is an environment variable. If i type 'gams' into the prompt i get a valid license. I could also open the gams programm normally. So the License appear to be valid, but pyomo could not find it anymore.
The same is with baron. This error is idependent of the problem i want solve.
Could anybody help me please?
